# Print an exponential

Tags: c

I'm creating a program that compares numbers with their respective exponents, and indicates which of the three is the smallest. The problem is that I wouldn't want it to perform the operation, for example:

Let's say the smallest number was $4^{8}$, so it would calculate that value, but I want it to just print "4^8" on the screen, or related things, but without doing that operation (in this case, it prints 65536).

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, smaller, x, y, z, for_a, for_b, for_c;

    printf("first value: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Second value: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Third value: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    printf("Value of x: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Value of y: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("Value of z: ");
    scanf("%d", &z);

    for_a= pow(a, x);
    for_b= pow(b, y);
    for_c= pow(c, z);

    if (for_a< for_b && for_a < for_c){
        smaller= for_a;
    }
    else if (for_b < for_c){
        smaller = for_b;
    }
    else {
        smaller = for_c;
    }

    printf("Smaller= %d\n", smaller);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try to add 2 other variables, base and power, and inside the if else, assign them to the right value : for example; if smaller = for_a, you would do base = a and power = x; and finally printf base + "^" + power

Comment: It's not clear what prevents you from printing the components rather than the final calculated value. You already have the values there so why don't you just go ahead and do that? Nobody is forcing you to print `smaller` if that's not what you want.

Comment: @oubaydos Great idea. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to identify the set of data that corresponds to your result. Storing the result only is not enough.

You could do this as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#typedef struct values_s{
  int base;
  int exponent;
  int result;
} values_t;

#define NUMBER_OF_VALUES 3

int main(void)
{
    values_t values[NUMBER_OF_VALUES];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_VALUES; i++)
    {
        printf("Base value #%d: ", i+1);
        fflush(stdout);
        int result = scanf("%d", &values[i].base);
        // TODO: Error handling in case result != 1
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_VALUES; i++)
    {
        printf("Exponent #%d: ", i+1);
        fflush(stdout);
        int result = scanf("%d", &values[i].exponent);
        // TODO: Error handling in case result != 1
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_VALUES; i++)
    {
        values[i].result = pow(values[i].base, values[i].exponent);
    }

    int smallest = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < NUMBER_OF_VALUES; i++)
    {
        if (values[i].result < values[smallest].result)
        {
            smallest = i;
        }
    }

    printf("Smallest: %d^%d = %d\n", values[smallest].base, values[smallest].exponent, values[smallest].result);

    return 0;
}
```

This is based on the assumptions that your variables of type `int` are large enough to hold the values you are dealing with. Otherwise you need to adjust accordingly.